# Cloudflare Clear Cache For One URL, Convert Curl Command to Drupal::httpClient() Or php

Tags: caching, http-request

I am creating a custom module to clear caches on cloudflare for one url.
**The original curl command:**

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/123456789/purge_cache" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer 123456789" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"files": ["https://example.com", {"url": "https://example.com/my-url"}]}'
```

**Drupal::httpClient**

```
try {
  $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
  $url = "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/123456789/purge_cache";
  $options = [
    'headers' => [
      'Authorization' => 'Bearer 123456789',
    ],
    'json' => [
      'files' => 'https://example.com',
      'url' => 'https://example.com/my-url'
    ],
  ];
  $response = $client->request('POST', $url, $options);
  $code = $response->getStatusCode();
  if ($code == 200) {
    return $code;
  }
}
catch (RequestException $e) {
  watchdog_exception('module_name', $e);
}
```

**php version:**

```
$data = Json::encode(['files' => 'https://example.com', 'url' => 'https://example.com/my-url' ] );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/123456789/purge_cache');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer 123456789';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I got one working by clearing all caches on clouldflare.
Original:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/123456789/purge_cache" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer 123456789" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"purge_everything":true}'
```

**The working Drupal Version:**

```
    try {
      $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
      $options = [
        'json' => [
          'purge_everything' => TRUE,
        ],
        'headers' => [
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $authorization,
        ],
      ];
      $response = $client->request($method, $url, $options);
      $code = $response->getStatusCode();
      if ($code == 200) {
        return $code;
      }
    }
    catch (RequestException $e) {
      watchdog_exception('cloudflare_purge', $e);
    }
```

The drupal version return 200, but it is not doing anything and the php version I could not get it work. I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Cloudflare has a PHP SDK that [supports zone cache purging](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001661191-Cloudflare-PHP-API-Binding). You'd be better off including that in your module's Composer dependencies instead of having to build your own CF API client.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-files-by-url
**I found the solution, so this command**:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/abcdefghijklabcdefghijkl/purge_cache" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer abcdefghijklabcdefghijkl" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"files": ["https://example.com", {"url": "https://example.com/url"}]}'
```

**It will be in Drupal like:**

```
      $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
      $options = [
        'headers' => [
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer abcdefghijklabcdefghijkl',
        ],
        'json' => [
          'files' => ['https://example.com/url']
        ],
      ];
      $response = $client->request('POST', $url, $options);
      $data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
      $data = json_decode($data, TRUE);
      if ($data['success']  == TRUE){
        return TRUE;
      }
```